# How to FIX Output ¤+ to ¥ or $ in python (Currency Formatting)

Tags: python, flask

how to change currency formatting output -> ¤+ <- to yuan (¥)

```
@app.route("/tes")
def tes():
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'cny')
    totalPrice = locale.currency( 18000, grouping=True)
    format(totalPrice)
    return totalPrice
```

OUTPUT -> ¤+18,000.00

I want to be like this OUTPUT -> ¥18,000.00

Thank you

Comment: Is your intent to return HTML? It should have a `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag, probably. (If plain text, add a `Content-Type` header with `text/plain;charset=utf-8`.)

Comment: i try <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> not working